# Solving Equations Regarding Modular

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

`146x = 12 (mod 421)`

I found out that 421 is a prime number and I still did not know how to start after going over the notes

I feel like it is similar to solve `7x = 1 (mod 180)` if I know how to solve one of them, any tips? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

Do you know how to use the
[Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)
to find a positive integer $r$ such that $(146)r \equiv 1\pmod{421}?$
If so, given that $(146)x \equiv 12 \pmod{421},$ what could you say about
$(146)(r)(x)$, which must be congruent to $(12)r \pmod{421}?$

Comment: Yes, I figured it out already. It was in my notes. So I just multiply both sides by the inverse right?

Comment: @Bob Yes, exactly.  Also, I would encourage you to review [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), so that going forward, your mathSE queries will be of high quality.

Comment: Thanks, I have another random question: since I now know how to solve modular equation, what about simplifying 4^103 mod 180

Comment: @Bob The short answer is: find a Number Theory book that (at some point in the book) attacks that question, open the book to page 1, and go forward.  I am not being deliberately obtuse.  The question that you have asked requires some **moderately** heavy Number Theory machinery to master.  It would be somewhat onerous for me to have to encapsulate this machinery in a series of comments.

Comment: Got it, but I think I have figured it out by myself again XD. Thanks for the hints and advice of mathSE. Have a good day :D

Comment: @Bob:  regarding your other question, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Nice response; good shooting the gap.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.

Comment: @BillDubuque Good point.  I've never considered that before.